# SQL Server client execution time in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm creating a tool for testing SQL query performance.  The tool needs to measure the client result return time as they would experience if they ran the query and had the results returned to the console.  However because this tool will run the query many times and eventually across multiple threads I don't want to display the query results on the screen.

I can get the times correctly if I display the results to the screen but if redirected to a variable the times are incorrect (to fast).

Any ideas?

Below is the portion of the test code I have.  I measure the difference of the start and end time to find the number of milliseconds.  Thank you.

```
    DateTime beginTime = DateTime.Now;
    cn2.Open();

    try
    {
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(cmd, cn2);
        SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();

        IDictionary d = cn2.RetrieveStatistics();
        string[] keys = new string[d.Count];
        d.Keys.CopyTo(keys, 0);

        for (int x = 0; x < d.Count; x++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", keys[x], (long)d[keys[x]]);
        }

        Int32.TryParse(d["ExecutionTime"].ToString(), out actualTimeMilliseconds);

        do
        {
            int count = reader.FieldCount;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.GetValue(i));
                }
            }
        } while (reader.NextResult());

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }

    cn2.Close();
    DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan clientTime = endTime.Subtract(beginTime);
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what the problem is is here.  Why can't you just write the results to a file?  Why is "*its too fast*" an issue at all?

Comment: @RBarryYoung I want to simulate the user experience.  I can already capture the time it takes to make the call but I want to also capture the time to display without displaying the results to the screen or a file.

Comment: By "*capture*" do you mean "*emulate*"?  Because normally "*capture*" in performance means to "measure and record", and ideally that's supposed to be as fast as possible so as not to interfere with the measurements.

Comment: @RBarryYoung You would be correct.  I know it can be measured because another app I'm replicating behavior of that does not have functionality I need.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Have I properly clarified the question.

Answer (score 0):

output redirects can be a problem because somebody has to remember to do it. As an alternative open the file in your console app and add the values at the end of the run.

```
  // Create a new file 
  using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(fileName))
  {
      sw.WriteLine("New file created: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString());
  }
```